# How to create an extension method on IHtmlHelper<dynamic>

Tags: html-helper, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

[This article](http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2012/08/func-and-action-basics-in-c.html) shows how to create an extension method on `HtmlHelper<dynamic>`, but it doesn't appear to work with MVC6 (I changed HtmlHelper to IHtmlHelper).

The error is:

```
'IHtmlHelper<PagedList<Tag>>' does not contain a definition for 'CustomSelectList' and the best extension method overload 'HtmlHelperExtensions.CustomSelectList<Tag>(IHtmlHelper<dynamic>, string, IEnumerable<Tag>, Func<Tag, string>, Func<Tag, string>)' requires a receiver of type 'IHtmlHelper<dynamic>'
```

How is this done in MVC6?

Comment: Your comments talk about `IHtmlHelper<dynamic>`, while your error message specifies `IHtmlHelper<PagedList<Tag>>`. Unless you're using `dynamic` for your model (by not specifying a `@model` directive), you'll need to make your helper method generic.

Comment: @MattDeKrey, if I make it generic, will the generic type be the type of the model? What I actually wanted was the ability to use the `Tag` type within the PagedList. So something like: `@model PagedList<Tag>` and then `@Html.OrderByLinkFor(t => t.Name)` (where `t` is `Tag` and not `PagedList<Tag>`). Is this possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The extension method needs to be on `IHtmlHelper` and not on `HtmlHelper<dynamic>`.

```
public static HtmlString CustomSelectList<T>(
    this IHtmlHelper html,
    string selectId,
    IEnumerable<T> list,
    Func<T, string> getName,
    Func<T, string> getValue)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.AppendFormat("<select id=\"{0}\">", selectId);
    foreach (T item in list)
    {
        builder.AppendFormat("<option value=\"{0}\">{1}</option>",
            getValue(item),
            getName(item));
    }
    builder.Append("</select>");
    return new HtmlString(builder.ToString());
}
```

Usage:

```
@(Html.CustomSelectList<Tag>("myId", Model, t => t.Name, t => t.Id.ToString()))
```

Comment: Where is this information from? I've always seen `HtmlHelper` used, and I can't seem to find any information on `IHtmlHelper`. Certainly, I can't establish any reference to it.